# Fade out - while scrolling

Tags: jquery

There are a LOT of examples doing a fadeOut complete animation when the user scrolls down. However, those animations do a **complete** *fadeIn* or *fadeOut* without taking into consideration the user scroll.

If the user scrolls a little up, it fades out a little, let's say 30%, of it keeps scrolling up, it will fade out more 30% and so forth...

I need to craft something like that, but I need something to look at, to get started.

Does anyone have some examples to share that use this effect?

Side note:
I need to apply a fadeOut on all elements that start to "leave" the viewport from the top, when we scroll down, and make then fadeIn when we scroll up again. This is just a context. I'm not asking for someone to do this code for me, but I need a kick start of a given proper example.

Anyone please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick example:

Note: I'm animating `opacity` change with CSS3 transtion.

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    $('img').css('opacity', (100-scroll)/100)
});
```

```css
html,body{
    height:10000px;
}

img{
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://pngimg.com/upload/beer_PNG2353.png">
```

Comment: It seems brilliantly simple. I will proper study it, and adapt. Instead of fading the all element at once, I will need to fade only the top part of it, little by little, as they go off the page. But that's definitely a start. Thanks for that.